# executeUpdate is not working

Tags: mysql, database, eclipse, jsp, prepared-statement

I can't seem to get my prepared statements to execute. For the output message, I got "0 flight successfully updated" instead of "1 flight successfully updated". My database connection(in the db.Conn package) is working and there are no visible errors on Eclipse itself.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*, dbConn.*" %>

            String flightid=request.getParameter("id");
            String aircraftid=request.getParameter("aircraftid");
            String OAirport=request.getParameter("OAirport");
            String OCountry=request.getParameter("OCountry");
            String DAirport=request.getParameter("DAirport");
            String DCountry=request.getParameter("DCountry");
            String ecost1=request.getParameter("ecost");
            String bccost1=request.getParameter("bccost");
            String fccost1=request.getParameter("fccost");
            String DDate=request.getParameter("DDate");
            String DTime=request.getParameter("DTime");
            String ADate=request.getParameter("ADate");
            String ATime=request.getParameter("ATime");
            String FT=request.getParameter("FT");
            String DR=request.getParameter("DiscountRate");


            Connection conn=database.getConnection();
            String sql="Update flightschedule F ,promotion P set F.aircraftid=?, F.OAirport=?,F.OCountry=?,F.DAirport=?,F.DCountry=?, F.ECost=?, F.BCcost=?,F.FCcost=?, F.DDate=?,F.DTime=?,F.ADate=?,F.ATime=?,F.Flighttime=?, P.DiscountRate=? where  F.flightid=P.flightid and F.flightid=? ";
            PreparedStatement pstmt=conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            pstmt.setString(1, flightid);
            pstmt.setInt(2, Integer.parseInt(aircraftid));
            pstmt.setString(3, OAirport); 
            pstmt.setString(4, OCountry);
            pstmt.setString(5, DAirport);
            pstmt.setString(6, DCountry);
            pstmt.setString(7, ecost1);
            pstmt.setString(8, bccost1);
            pstmt.setString(9, fccost1);
            pstmt.setString(10, DDate);
            pstmt.setString(11, DTime);
            pstmt.setString(12, ADate);
            pstmt.setString(13, ATime);
            pstmt.setString(14, FT);
            pstmt.setString(15,DR);

            int count=pstmt.executeUpdate();
            out.println(count+ " flight successfully updated");
            conn.close();

            %>
```

Here are my 2 databases:

https://s9.postimg.org/xcaujfq0f/promotion_table.jpg
https://s23.postimg.org/9bawk28u3/flight_schedule.jpg

I have a foreign key of FlightID from Promotion referencing to Flight ID of FlightSchedule.

P.S I know about the MVC architecture but I want to solve this problem first before using Servlets.

Comment: The parameters are replaced according to the number your use. E.g. the first `?` in the query, `set F.aircraftid=?`, will become `pstmt.setString(1, flightid);`, which is not what you want. So reassign your parameters correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You are ordering/setting the `PreparedStatement` parameter incorrectly, try the following:

```
pstmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(aircraftid));
pstmt.setString(2, OAirport); 
pstmt.setString(3, OCountry);
pstmt.setString(4, DAirport);
pstmt.setString(5, DCountry);
pstmt.setString(6, ecost1);
pstmt.setString(7, bccost1);
pstmt.setString(8, fccost1);
pstmt.setString(9, DDate);
pstmt.setString(10, DTime);
pstmt.setString(11, ADate);
pstmt.setString(12, ATime);
pstmt.setString(13, FT);
pstmt.setString(14,DR);
pstmt.setString(15, flightid);
```